# How do I mark the link in the navigation I visit? SharePoint 2010

Tags: 2010, master-page, navigation, hyperlink

I have created a new navigation to a flat site collection on SharePoint 2010. But the navigation looks like this:

[image: Navigation]

I want to move the marker from "Home" to the page I visit. But I have no clue on how to manage it. Do you know how I can make the change?

Comment: Do you mean you want to change the link to always point to the current page ?

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean.

Comment: I don't believe there would be a "Configuration-only" way to have this dynamic behavior. And I do not know enough about the Navigation API in SP to give you further instructions ;).

Comment: Alright, to bad but thanks for your time :)

Comment: Are you giving relative URLs to the pages in Navigation?

Comment: I give them there URL like this:
SPContext.Current.Web.Url + "/" + item.Url

Comment: Is this custom navigation control.do you have the freedom to write/change code?

Comment: This is not a custom navigation control. It's a home made control.
It picks information about the pages in a list and then puts the child pages under parent pages.
Yes, I can change the code.